# Does “gay” still include the meaning “merry”?

Tags: meaning-in-context, offensive-language, archaicisms, sexual-minorities

- Dictionary.com lists [eight meanings
  of *gay*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/gay), with “merry, lively” as
  the first entry.
- Microsoft [banned an
  Xbox user](http://www.tgdaily.com/games-and-entertainment-features/51450-microsoft-apologizes-over-xbox-live-gay-snafu) for listing [Fort
  Gay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fort_Gay,_West_Virginia) (a real place) as his
  hometown:

  > Xbox Live considered the term *gay* absolutely inappropriate in any context.

As a non-native English speaker, my question is whether in contemporary English, does *gay* always mean *homosexual*? Are British and American English the same in this respect?

Comment: According to the article, Microsoft ultimately did make it right. It was just a couple frontline employees who are trained to be hypersensitive about people using the word *gay* in a pejorative way who acted in a typical bureaucratic (read *ham-fistedly insensitive to context*) way.

Comment: To be pedantic, *gay* and *homosexual* don't mean quite the same thing. In fact, that's not just pedantic: it's important. http://www.salon.com/life/broadsheet/2010/02/12/gay_homosexual

Comment: @TRiG, *gay* and *homosexual* do **mean** [="denote"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denotation) the same thing. It's that they imply [="connote"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connotation) different things.

Comment: @nohat, I would have thought that the meaning included both the definition and the associations of a word.

Comment: Examples of changed meanings can be found at http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HaveAGayOldTime.

Comment: @TRiG I think the confusion by what exactly “meaning” entails is why semanticists make the sharp distinction between denotation and connotation. If all the nuances of words’ connotations were always included in “meaning” then no two things could ever mean the same thing.

Comment: @nohat: Being *ham-fistedly insensitive to context* seems to be the only way Microsoft treats *the term "gay"*. Some time ago they removed words *blue* and *pink* from the Russian language spell checker database in Russian MS Office. *Blue* is used to denote a male gay person in Russian, and *pink* denotes a female gay person. So if you were to type "The sky is blue" or "I love my new pink shoes" in Russian, it would underline the words.

Comment: @GSerg, as both a gay person and a former employee of Microsoft, I can assure you that you are incorrect about Microsoft. It is a very large organization and some people are ignorant, but as a whole the corporation is not totally insensitive to context and is in fact very progressive.

Comment: @nohat: Yes, that's what I would think, and, as a matter of fact, I did when I first heard about the Fort Gay incident. It did seem like there was just one ignorant person responsible for the ban, not the corporation as a whole. But my mental image on banning words from a spell checker involves several layers of management, all approving the ban. Yes, I may be wrong on that, too, so feel free to adjust this mental image of mine. And obviously, I'm not saying Microsoft has little tolerance to gay *people*, I'm only talking about the word itself.

Comment: @GSerg - in MSFT's defence they weren't doing it to be homophobic but as an anti bullying measure, to stop people creating accounts like "joel_is_gay" to taunt other kids.

Comment: @GSerg, funny thing, the word in Russian doesn't mean blue. The problem is that it is SPELLED same way as the word blue. It's a homophone and homograph with a different root (related to archaic word for "molest"). Why they removed pink, that's beyond me. But it was time of Office 95, which had tendency to crash when encountering some hyphen-spelled words.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I would say that the word *gay* means ‘homosexual’ only, with two caveats:

1. A lot of people, especially young people, use *gay* as a generic adjective meaning ‘bad’ or ‘lame’. This is, of course, considered inappropriate and rude by polite society, but use of *gay* in this way is pervasive in situations where there are a lot of young people, such as video gaming communities (like XBox Live).
2. People are definitely aware that *gay* used to mean ‘happy’, ‘merry’, or ‘lively’. The theme song to *The Flintstones* talks about a *gay old time*, and many people know that this usage at one time was predominant. There is a similar situation with the word *queer*. Some people might use *gay* to mean ‘merry’, but only in a tongue-in-cheek or double-entendre kind of way. The [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=6121377), for example, has two examples of “gay old time”, one from 1993, and one from 1994. There is one more example that is from the big screen adaptation of *The Flintstones*, also released in 1994.

Comment: Didn't the Flintstones change their song to "we'll have a great old time" by the time the Flintstones movie came around?

Comment: @Kosmonaut: Apparently not: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VhdihISj628&feature=related

Comment: Hm.  Well I know that at *some* point "gay" was turned into "great", but they might have had second thoughts about it when the movie came out.

Comment: If they were going to replace "gay", I would have thought "grand" would fit better than "great".

Comment: Well, *gay* and *great* are near-rhymes, but *grand* has a different vowel sound. In any case, this is one instance of what I was talking about: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7daa4NF99XQ

Comment: I wouldn't take 1) as a caveat, since it is specifically the homosexual meaning which delivers the "lame" (i.e. that's the whole point), but I presume you apprehend that.

Comment: The novel *Caldicott Place* by Noel Streatfield, includes several times the phrase "Alfie's queer", by which is meant that he has an upset stomach.

Comment: @horatio, yes that is definitely true, but I included it as a caveat because apologists for gay-meaning-bad often say that the word (in that usage) has become entirely divorced from the homosexual meaning, and thus it’s “OK” (meaning not inherently homophobic) to use it.

Comment: You missed the opportunity to say that the old definition isn't "played straight" anymore.

Comment: There's also a 1997 Bob Dylan song, Standing In The Doorway, "I'm strummin' on my gay guitar." "Gay" here means "colorful".

Comment: @user155624 I can also add  The Dark is Rising series by Susan Cooper, which was reprinted a few times, even recently (and is present on Kindle). The word gay was used there a few times, as merry and in one particular case as "colorful", "bright", "drawing attention" - "a gift in gay wrapper" - a chiefly British meaning. The original books were written between 1965 and 1970s.

Answer (score 7):

In **contemporary** English, I would say that yes, *gay* means homosexual only.

Its original meaning was, as you mention, *merry* or *lively*, and you will certainly see it used this way if you look at written English from a few decades ago. However, it's very unlikely you'd see it used that way today.

Comment: Wikipedia has a [huge article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gay) on the subject.

Comment: OK, thanks. And thanks to RegDwight for the Wikipedia link.

Comment: I find it fabulous that @RegDwight has commented ont this topic :)

Comment: @John: to be fair, it was [Bernie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernie_Taupin) who wrote that comment for me.

Comment: it also means "lame", see nohat's answer.

Answer (score 5):

In commonly used English today, "gay" has become interchangeable with "homosexual" and most readers will understand it in that way, either as an adjective or as a noun. Though I'm not a fan of the plural form "gays".

As always, though, context is the most important thing because the English language is fabulously ambiguous towards the meaning of *gay.* There are certain phrases, which admittedly are not in common usage, but where the reader would understand that the word *gay* would not mean "homosexual" unless there was a clear double meaning, e.g. "gay hue" or "gay abandon". Also, applying *gay* to transient things, such as a mood, would probably alert the reader to the fact you did indeed mean "happy".

In addition, "gaily" and "gaiety" would not be generally understood as pertaining to homosexuality though they are usually only used in archaic contexts. Unless perhaps the writer meant "gaiety" in terms of stereotypical homosexual behaviour, e.g. "there was much gaiety" could mean "everyone was acting in a very camp manner", or perhaps something like "there were many men who were proud to be gay".

Personally, because I am caught between favouring clear and concise language and loving the use of flowery, overblown and overwrought, archaic language, I try to reserve the word *gay* for when I mean "merry". I also enjoy the possibilities of secondary meanings.

Answer (score 2):

Gay is also a last name. My high school music teacher was Mrs. Gay.

I disagree with every answer that says Gay *only* means homosexual, especially when the question already points out that there is a place named Fort Gay. That's the kind of thinking that got Microsoft in hot water in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe we should reclaim the word "gay" to mean "merry" and "care free", by using it in this sense all the time. This would make the word less effective as a derogatory word.

The word were originally used by the gay (in this case homosexual) community because it were a positive term.

I feel quite gay right now. ;)

Answer (score 1):

A number of words kept their old meanings (in America) through the 1960s, but changed their meanings decisively as a result of the "sexual revolution" that took place in the late 1960s and early 1970s.

"Gay" and "queer" are two words that have predominantly one connotation after 1970. The (original) Flintstones came out before this time.

Answer (score 0):

In UK English, the word *gay* has changed its meaning more than any other any word in recent times IMO.

In late 19th century English, a “gay girl” was a prostitute.

The word **also** meant lively and happy; hence the daft old dance the Gay Gordons, which involved everyone jumping around and shouting “Hoots Mon”.

Gay was also quite a common girls’ name.

In the 1970s there was something called “The Gay Liberation Front”, the first well known and well publicized organization fighting for the rights of homosexual males. This is where the meaning of *gay* for homosexual comes from. I would guess that before then, this meaning of *gay* was only used in “homosexual slang” — that is, between themselves.

More recently *gay* as an adjective meaning a lame person or thing, has come into use among very young people, mostly of school age. This usage has been frowned upon by many older people.

In the 1970s there was a very popular gay **and very camp** comedian who would play on the ambiguities of meaning, and say things like “I’m feeling very gay today.”

Comment: [Etymology of the word 'gay'](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=gay)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, that asks about specifically about contemporary English.