# Would it be a mistake to use the word "gay" in business or academical writings?

Tags: meaning, sexual-minorities, language-change

This is a post by NiceTryDad on instagram.

> **Son**: "What does the word "gay" mean?"
>   **Me**: "It means happy."
>   **Son**: "Oh, are you gay?"
>   **Me**: "No, son, I have a wife."

Later then, I googled up the meaning of the word "gay". And I found that it has some meanings in its older use, like **having or showing a merry**, **lively mood**, and also **bright** or **showy**. And also, [this site](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/gay) explains:

> Gay meaning ‘homosexual’ became established in the 1960s as the term preferred by homosexual men to describe themselves. It is now the standard accepted term throughout the English-speaking world. As a result, the centuries-old other senses of gay meaning either ‘carefree’ or ‘bright and showy’ have more or less dropped out of natural use. The word gay cannot be readily used today in these older senses without arousing a sense of double entendre, despite concerted attempts by some to keep them alive. Gay in its modern sense typically refers to men (lesbian being the standard term for homosexual women) but in some contexts it can be used of both men and women

I know that that post was just a joke, but I'm wondering if I can use the word *gay* to indicate that someone's happy in business or academical writings. Since people would always refer it to its modern sense (homosexuality).

Comment: It's not clear from this question if you understand that the quoted post is a joke based on the two definitions of "gay". Another related post: [Does “gay” still include the meaning “merry”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2772)

Comment: I don't find the joke to be  particularly amusing or clever though.  You can still be "gay", be married and have children, nowadays. I suppose calling your samesex partner, if he is a man, your "wife" is very uncommon. But if **me** is a female, then the joke might be funnier. (She can't be *gay* because she has a wife = is married)

Comment: @BillJ At least we agree on some things. It's quite amusing that there are those who complain bitterly about the even newer 'crazy / dicky / kaput' sense ('This deckchair's gay') but who welcomed the first hijacking.

Comment: [These two Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gay+colors%2Che+is+gay&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgay%20colors%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20is%20gay%3B%2Cc0) are interesting and doubtless relevant.

Comment: @Mari-LouA in addition to that, there's a joke, I'm not gay, my partner is (assuming both same-sex)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Sounds good. Doesn't work. That was posted by NiceTryDad on instagram. So the **me** has to be a dad (male).

Comment: About 20 years ago I read an article that asserted that "gay", with the meaning of "homosexual", was adopted from a similar French term which was in turn adopted from an Arabic/North African term along the lines of "gayje".  However, on a couple of occasions since I have searched the web for mention of this and have not found anything.  Although just now I found [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gayle_language).

Comment: There are other word we can use for "happy and merry" ... use the other words ... we can't always make our own rules and when the word shift has come to be associated with important social relations that have had a history of adversarial politics associated, one can't simply feign innocence about the new meaning.  Forcing the old use can't be seen as merely using a word you would like to see alive in a vacuum

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You ask:

> I know that that was a joke, but is it still appropriate to say gay to refer that someone's happy or merry these days? Like in writings or something.

When words have multiple meanings, each individual meaning can be used appropriately, given suitable context. The tricky part is to make sure that the context constrains the word to only the meaning or meanings that are intended.

For example, saying "the yolk has *set*" would almost certainly be understood to mean that it has hardened, particularly if the context is cooking. Saying "the sun has *set*" would usually *not* convey the same sense of the word *set* (i.e. that the sun has 'hardened') - it would instead almost certainly be read as talking about a period of time in the day-night cycle.

Now, when a word has undergone a [semantic shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_change), the context must work a lot harder to bring out the older meaning of the term. For example, *awful* no longer carries the sense of "full of awe", so one can't just speak of an "awful experience"; one might have to speak of an "ecstatic, blissful, or as the ancients might say, awful experience".

In the case of the word *gay*, popular usage these days would tend to default to the *homosexual* interpretation, but it's not a semantic shift. Both senses are understood, but since the *happy* sense of the word is no longer dominant, it requires more from the context.

So in short, yes, it's still appropriate to use the word *gay* in the sense of *happy*, so long as it's presented in appropriate context.

Comment: The usage of "gay" meaning "merry" and "happy" today is so very *gay*.  And very old-fashioned, and very quaint.

Comment: @IvanDi ["gay"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gay) also means "lame", "twee" or "effeminate". So I wouldn't recommend NNSs to use it, unless they can confidently avoid the ambiguity sense. Ack, just use the term "happy" and be done with it.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. In my native language there's also a word that means "lame" and sometimes being associated with homosexuality. But I've never confused with its usage before. And now I do.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: The alternate meanings of gay that you listed are referring to the meaning of "homosexual", with the added implication that it is bad. If the speaker does not think homosexuality is bad, then "gay" does not carry the meaning of e.g. "lame". E.g. if I call you "the Hitler of English.SE", there is an implication that I mean you act like a fascist dictator, because that is how most people stereotypically think of Hitler. But at _face value_, I could also simply be commending your oratory skill. This depends on the speaker's context, rather than an objective meaning.

Comment: This answer suggests that the term gay meaning "happy", "bright" and "cheerful" can still be used in everyday situations as long as the context is made clear. People nowadays simply do not use the term "gay" in its old fashioned sense. Knowing its original meaning is not the same as using it. Can you please provide a few examples dated from the mid1980s onwards where "gay = happy" is used.

Comment: @Flater try saying that Donald Trump ***speaks*** like Hitler and see how far you can get before someone agrees that DT ***acts*** like a fascist leader. The surname Hitler conjures: Nazism, the SS,  military oppression, concentration camps, 6 million dead jews, WWII, brainwashing, and propaganda. Maybe Hitlerian could be used in the way that you suggest but not the dictator's surname.

Comment: Hi @Mari-LouA :) ! I'm not sure whether this counts, so I'll just place it in the comments first. There's an ice cream called [Golden Gaytime](http://www.streetsicecream.com.au/Brand/Golden_Gaytime.aspx) that uses *gay* as *happy* (I know, names don't count, but the connotation does). The page notes that the name goes back to 1959, so before your mid-1980s timeframe, but it's still around today, at least in Australia. My answer notes that *happy* is now no longer the dominant sense of *gay*, but simply that given *appropriate context*, it is still within the semantic range of the word.

Comment: Do Australians make fun of the ice cream brand name? I bet they do. Moreover "Gaytime" is not identical to "gay" It's a compound noun, and its a brand. I don't consider it a pertinent example. You do well to leave it in the comments.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Perhaps they do, but I haven't noticed it in conversation.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Here's a comment on the [M-W](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/gay) page that says "Hog wash that 'happy', 'merry','colourful', 'exuberant' or the like, are old fashioned meanings of the wonderfully easy word to express delight - that is gay!" The date stamp says 3 years ago. Granted, it's a comment - but you asked for usage references, so it counts. :)

Comment: https://www.buzzfeed.com/lanesainty/this-is-for-everyone-who-doesnt-know-about-golden-gaytimes?utm_term=.wlLpkB8g0y#.om7ldrG60m The manufacturers of Gaytime have a memorable brand name and they're sticking to it. And no, a comment posted on M-W disputing that "gay" isn't old fashioned doesn't count. It's actually inaccurate.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Ok, here's another, in line with my note about semantic shift and context: ["Oh, it was such a gay party, and by that definition I don’t mean gay gay, just a good time."](http://www.agcwebpages.com/BLINDITEMS/2007/SEPTOCT.html)

Comment: Which proves I'm absolutely right, the speaker qualifies his statement by use of duplication, he's saying "such a gay party" is not the same as "gay gay = homosexual, he *has* to make sure his readers do not misunderstand him. Perfect example of what I was saying.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Then we're in agreement. :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA _"try saying that Donald Trump **speaks** like Hitler and see how far you can get before someone agrees that DT **acts** like a fascist leader."_ I can't stop people from making assumptions or wrong inferences; but that does not mean that I used the word wrongly. Correctness is not defined solely by the recipient of the message and what they implicitly take away from it.

Comment: @Flater Here's a piece of advice, if you want to compliment someone on their oratory skills, don't compare them to Adolf Hitler. It won't be taken the way you think it should.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: You're focusing on the actual example, rather than the discussion that sparked it. Yes, my example was extreme. Simplified examples often are, so that they can show a stark contrast without needing to explain little nuances which complicate the example more than they support the answer by providing "more reality".

Comment: @Flater you brought up Adolf Hitler not me. I was reminding Lawrence that "gay" also has a third, rather derogatory meaning, which he completely omitted, or chose to ignore in his answer.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thanks for the reminder. I missed that third meaning completely in my answer.

Comment: You mean all those comments we exchanged and you didn't get the point I was making? No one has ever said was I was subtle–hooray! I have mastered the art of diplomacy!

Comment: @Mari-LouA Haha! No, I got it when you posted your first comment above. I meant that my answer didn't address it at all.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer this but please don't anyone get on my case because I have no opinion on the matter. I don't want to offend anyone but I do want to offer an honest answer.

For most people in the US, or native English speakers, the first thing that will come to mind when they hear "gay" will be "homosexual". However, it's perfectly okay to use the word "gay" to mean "merry, lively, and/or happy". When it is used in that way it is more often in writing versus in speech.

The bottom line is if you walk up to many people and say, "I'm feeling very gay today.", they are going to think you mean you are homosexual. The mature ones will likely understand what you mean from your context and attitude. The immature ones will snicker and laugh.

Comment: Can you add examples of its usage in writings? Even, is there still any writing that use it that way?

Comment: @IvanDi Yes, there are still writings that use 'gay' that way. One of my favorite Christmas songs has a verse that says: _Have yourself a merry little Christmas,
Make the Yule-tide gay,
From now on, 
our troubles will be miles away_  https://www.carols.org.uk/have_yourself_a_merry_little_christmas.htm

Comment: @Phil14 - Those lyrics are from 1943. It still meant ’merry’ then.

Comment: @Phil14 It still meant 'merry' in 1961, try the Flintstones lyric _"When you're with the Flintstones / Have a yabba-dabba-doo time / A dabba-doo time 
/ We'll have a gay old time"_. Personally I always suspected that 'gay' was a Polari term for homosexual derived from 'bachelor gay' long before anyone coined the acronym GAY from Good As You, but as a straight guy what do I know?